# Sending message from one application to another application in the same terminal

Tags: .net, winforms

I have developed a windows application which is installed on about 15 machines on the client side. I have created self update functionality in the application. Self update functionality is just small console application in the main application.

When main application starts, it compares its version (from config file) with the database (a table which stores the latest version). If both versions are different then console application is executed and main application is stopped.

Console application closes all the instances of the main application and picks latest files of main application from a central place and updates the application.

The problem is when console application closes all the instances of main application, users should get a notification message that "application will be closed for updation blah blah ...".

I did rnd for that and found the send message function that sends messages to other processes. Send Message works fine for multiple instances on the same machine. All the instances shows message before they are closed.

But it does not work on terminal when 2 or more users are using the application on the same terminal/server. Application is closed without giving any notification message to the user. On terminal each user logs in with their username and password and can work independently.

**Below is the code I have implement: **

```
**Console application that sends the messgae**

private const int RF_TESTMESSAGE = 0xA123;

[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
public static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hwnd, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] int   Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

var processFinder = new ManagementObjectSearcher(string.Format("Select * from Win32_Process where Name='{0}.exe'", processName));
    var processes = processFinder.Get();
    if (processes.Count == 0)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        foreach (ManagementObject managementObject in processes)
        {
            var n = Convert.ToString(managementObject["Name"]);
            var pId = Convert.ToInt32(managementObject["ProcessId"]);
            var process = Process.GetProcessById(pId);

            process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

            if (currentUserOnly) //current user
            {
                var processOwnerInfo = new object[2];
                managementObject.InvokeMethod("GetOwner", processOwnerInfo);
                var processOwner = (string)processOwnerInfo[0];
                var net = (string)processOwnerInfo[1];
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(net))
                    processOwner = string.Format("{0}\\{1}", net, processOwner);



                if (string.CompareOrdinal(processOwner, userName) == 0)
                {
                    SendMessage(process.MainWindowHandle, RF_TESTMESSAGE, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
                }

                if (process.HasExited == false) // if application has not closed
                {

                    //Process is still running.
                    //Test to see if the process is hung up.
                    if (process.Responding) // if user interface of process is still responding 
                    {
                        //  Process was responding; close the main window.
                        process.CloseMainWindow();


                        if (process.HasExited == false) // if application is still running then close kill the process
                        {
                            process.Kill();

                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // Process was not responding; force the process to close.
                        process.Kill();

                    }
                }

                process.WaitForExit(5000);

                UpdateSoftware = process.HasExited;
                process.Close(); 
            }
        }

    }
```

**Main Application that recieves the message**

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
public static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hwnd, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] int Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

protected override void WndProc(ref Message message)
{
    //filter the RF_TESTMESSAGE
    if (message.Msg == RF_TESTMESSAGE)
    {
        //display that we recieved the message, of course we could do
        //something else more important here.

        MessageBox.Show("Your application will be closed becuase new update is available. Please start the application after some time.");
    }
    //be sure to pass along all messages to the base also
    base.WndProc(ref message);
}
```

Please let me know where I am wrong? Why is it not working for users on the same terminal?

Comment: The windows for different users are in different sessions, and you can't send window messages between sessions.

Comment: Then is there any other way out to send message?

Comment: Any cross-session signalling technique will tend to be a bit flaky or require that (at least one) user on the machine is an administrator - is such the case, or are the user accounts just normal user accounts?

Comment: These are just normal user accounts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After so many days i found the solution. By using Cassia .NET library we can send messages to across sessions. Here is the link for the library http://code.google.com/p/cassia

```
private static readonly ITerminalServicesManager _manager = new TerminalServicesManager();
using (ITerminalServer server = GetServerFromName("local"))
            {
                server.Open();

                int i = 0;
                foreach (ITerminalServicesSession session in server.GetSessions())
                {
                    IEnumerable<ITerminalServicesProcess> processes = session.GetProcesses();

                    foreach (ITerminalServicesProcess p in processes)
                    {
                        if (p.ProcessName == "Your Process Name.exe")
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Process Name: {0} Process ID: {1} Session ID: {2}", p.ProcessName, p.ProcessId, p.SessionId));
                            if (i == 0)
                            {
                                session.MessageBox("Your application will be stopped for new updates", "Application Update", RemoteMessageBoxIcon.Warning);
                                i = 1;
                            }
                            p.Kill();
                        }
                    }

                    i = 0;
                }
            }
```